# How do I set up a dedicated IP address for a service in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip

I've got 2 IP addresses for my machine, examples:

- `x.x.x.1`
- `x.x.x.2`

My current server address is `x.x.x.1` and the server is running service A, B & C.

I would like to provide service A & B on `x.x.x.1` and..
I would like to provide service C on `x.x.x.2`

It should not be possible to reach services assigned to another IP address (i.e. reaching service C on `x.x.x.1` should not be possible).

---

I've already added the secondary IP address to my interface.

Contents of `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg`:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address x.x.x.2
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast x.x.x.2
```

How can I achieve my goal described above? Do I need to configure service C to bind on `x.x.x.2` only? And/or is it possible to configure this in the firewall?

Comment: Doesn't your services support the possibility to bind to a certain address? Most services do. Without knowledge of which services it's very difficult to help further.

Comment: You might want to look into containers like LXD, where you can run the service inside it and give the container its own ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to configure service C to bind on x.x.x.2 only?

The simple answer is Yes.

Normally, the OS doesn't determine the address used by services. OS just give the choice to application.

If a service bind to 0.0.0.0, it means that the service listen on any available address on the OS.